# Don't see new field in laravel DB after migration

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I had glass_posts table in database like that

```
        Schema::create('glass_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->string('slug', 255)->unique();
            $table->text('fulltext')->nullable();
            $table->string('image', 255)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('category_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('glass_categories')
                  ->onDelete('RESTRICT');

            $table->index('published');
        });
```

then I decided to insert one more field `gallery`

```
        Schema::create('glass_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->string('slug', 255)->unique();
            $table->text('fulltext')->nullable();
            $table->string('image', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('gallery', 255)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('category_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('glass_categories')
                  ->onDelete('RESTRICT');

            $table->index('published');
        });
```

So I delete glass_posts table from DB, then delete value `2020_03_29_104428_create_glass_tables` from migrations database and then I run `php artisan migrate`

Now when I go to DB I see table with new field, but when I output value from database `dd($item)` I see all fields, except `gallery`.
It is not clear for me why it is so.
I tried to clear cache, but no help.

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Is the gallery field set in t he row? would $model->gallery return something?

Comment: `dd($item)` returns all fields except gallery. `dd($item->gallery)` returns `null`

Comment: Is the gallery field set in the db on all rows or how are you doing it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How it is possible to set field not on all rows? Field is set on the table, which means it exists in each row.

Comment: yes, but if gallery is set on the model with id 1 to '42' and you call your model Model::find(1)->gallery. 100% it should return 42. I believe if this doesn't work you either have not set the gallery column or you do not have the correct model, you access gallery on.

Comment: I see gallery column when I go to DB directly using adminer. So gallery exists on each row. But when I try to output any item from this table `dd($item)` in the dump I don't see this gallery field. It looks very strange, but I don't have any special settings in my model

Comment: have you check your $fillables in model class?